# c# replace expression "except if"

Tags: c#, replace, substring

I am trying to repalce subtrings of a string, e.g.

```
this is some weird text that I want to format text for some ='custom text' content "text" ="text"...
```

Result should be

```
this is some weird sentence that I want to format sentence for some ='custom text' content "sentence" ="text"...
```

I want to replace all occurrences of `text`, with `sentence`, EXCEPT if the occurrence is contained within `='...'` or `="..."`.

Handling the EXACT quoted occurrence (i.e. `="test"` or `='test'`) is fairly easy, but I'm stuck whith the contained part....

I thought about Regex, but I'm not familiar enough with them to succeed...

Comment: What about "contextual"; should that replace the "text" with "sentence" and get "consentenceual"?  You are setting yourself up for clbuttic defects. Consider writing a lexer.

Comment: "consentenceual", sounds like something out of the #metoo movement.

Comment: I don't understand why in your example the `content "text"` is replaced.  You said you didn't want replacement if the `text` was in quotes, and it is.

Comment: What about `text="text='text="text='text` ?  How many of those are replaced, and why?  Your problem is underspecified.  **You are designing a programming language here, so do it carefully**.

Comment: @EricLippert Looks like the rule is it being contained in quotes (single or double) that are prefixed with a `=`

Comment: @JonathonChase: Ah, I get it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I know it doesn't seem like it, but you are designing a *language*. A very simple string-processing language in fact.  So approach the problem like you would approach designing a programming language.  Your workflow should be:

- Lex the input string into a sequence of tokens
- Transform the token sequence using your rule
- Convert the token sequence back into a string

The first one is the hard one, but it is not that hard. You can do it.

Your lexer can be modeled as a *state machine*.  That is:

- we keep track of a "current state"
- we process each character, one at a time
- processing depends on only two things: what character was it, and what state are we in?
- this generates two things: (1) a new current state (possibly the same as the old state) and (2) a decision yes or no, are we on a token boundary?
- If we are on a token boundary then we add a new token to the list of tokens.

When we've processed every character, we've got a list of tokens.

Let's look at some typical lexer rules for your example.  We always start by saying the states:

- There are four states: Normal, Equals, Single and Double
- We start in Normal state

Now say what to do in each state:

- In Normal state, if you get a `=`, end the current token if there is one, start a new Equals token, add the `=` to it, and go to Equals state. Otherwise, add the character to the current token if there is one, or create a new Normal token one if there is not.
- In Equals state, end the current token. If you get a `'` go to Single state and create a Single token. If you get a `"`, create a Double token and go to Double state. If you get a `=`, create an Equals token and stay in Equals state. Otherwise create a Normal token and go back to Normal state. Add the character to the current token.
- In Single state, add the character to the current token. If you get a `'`, go to Normal state. Otherwise, stay in Single state.
- Similarly for Double state.
- If you've run out of characters, end the current token.

And so on. You see how this goes.  We have a very simple little machine that is just going through all the characters and deciding what kind of text we've seen so far, and whether to break it up at this point or not.  You end up with a list of tokens, where each token has a portion of your string.

Now you can do search-and-replace on your Normal tokens, knowing that you will not be doing replacements on any of your Single, Double or Equals tokens.

Then put the replaced strings back together in the same order and you're done.

Comment: I take it that the normal tokens would also need a word boundary rule to end the current/start the next normal token, correct? Otherwise I'd expect incorrect replacements on words like, to borrow your example, `contextual`.

Comment: @JonathonChase: Right, that complicates the problem, but it reduces the complication to *just the normal tokens*. The problem can be solved on normal tokens, or the lexer can be improved. The point is that the problem of quoted strings has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!\=\s*?(\'[^']*)|(\"[^"]*))text
```

replace with `sentence`

This is doing a variable length negative lookbehind for `='`(and then not another apostrophe)..same with `"`.  Basically it'll reject the match if it finds that behind it.

This is still relatively fragile and can get blown up by escaped quotes or non-matching quotes, but depending on your data it might be acceptable.  It certainly will work with human supervision.

If strings like `Data='Bob said "Mary's not here yet" text'` are a serious concern, I would skip the regex approach.

Check here to see it:
[(Context tab)](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%3d%5cs*%3f%28%5c%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%29%7c%28%5c%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%29%29text&i=text%0d%0a%3d%27text%27%0d%0a%27text%27%0d%0a%3d%27word+text+word%27%0d%0a%3d%22word+text+word%22%0d%0a&r=sentence)